# Custom Report SilverStripe 3.1

Tags: silverstripe

I followed the docs to [create a custom report](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/how_tos/customise_site_reports/) but keep failing to generate the report in the CMS. Has anyone else had this problem? I noticed that with older versions, the config had to include the report, but I see no sign of this in 3.1.

Here is the contents of CustomSideReport.php

```
class CustomSideReport_Day extends SideReport {
    public function title() {
        return "Event Calendar";
    }

    public function records() {
        return Page::get()->sort("Title");
    }

    public function fieldsToShow() {
        return array(
            "Title" => array("NestedTitle", array("2"))
        );
    }
}
```

I have the done the usual `dev/build` and `flush`, but still nothing appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation has now been updated to correctly show how to make [custom site reports](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/how_tos/customise_site_reports/).

In SilverStripe 3.1 the class should extend `SS_Report` instead of `SideReport`.

Try this:

```php
class CustomSideReport_Day extends SS_Report {
    public function title() {
        return 'Event Calendar';
    }

    public function sourceRecords($params = null) {
        return Page::get()->sort('Title');
    }

    public function columns() {
        $fields = array(
            'Title' => 'Title'
        );

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Also note that `records()` has changed to `sourceRecords($params = null)` and `fieldsToShow()` has changed to `columns()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I actually just found this out by looking at the BrokenLinksReport.php in cms/code/reports and replicating. Thanks for the explanation